# How to mock $window.height()?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a directive that contains `$window.height()` and `$window.scrollTop()`. How can I create mock for `$window.height()` and `$window.scrollTop()`? Only then, I can write the test for that directive.

Comment: The `window` object doesn't have neither a `height()` method nor a `scrollTop` method. I guess you're wrapping it within a jQuery object.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$provide` in a `beforeEach` block to specify a mock `$window` object be used in place of `$window`.

Here's an example of testing an angular service called "myService" using a mock `$window` object:

```
describe("thingToTest", function () {
    "use strict";

    var service,
        $window;

    beforeEach(module("myModule"));

    beforeEach(function () {
        $window = {
            height: function () { //do something },
            scrollTop: function () { //do something }
        };

        module(function ($provide) {
            $provide.value('$window', $window);
        });

        inject(function ($injector) {
            service = $injector.get('myService');
        });
    });

    describe("myTests", function () {
    //tests here
    });
```

Comment: Just a heads-up: mocking `$window` out can sometimes break some Angular internal code that relies on that service. In those cases it's better to inject the `$window` service and mock just the methods your test needs.

Comment: @MichaelBenford I have did a sample here to better see the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/w4h5q5hr/. How can I overcome the issue?